# Convert signed fixed point to float

Tags: c, int, arm, fixed-point

**I have got number in this mode:**
Value mode = 16-bit fixed point (signed)

And how I can convert this number to floating point? Any idea?

Can I use this function, when this number is signed?

```
float toFloat(int16_t val) {
        return ((float)val)/256.0f;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "fixed point"? Is it of the form 123.45? Or is it just an integer?

Comment: It is data from gyroscope: [---LINK---](http://www.lp-research.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/LpmsAllUsersGuide1.3.4.pdf), page 45. And it is fixed point in form: `123.45` or `-123.45`

Comment: The linked data sheet shows factors of 100 or 1000, not 256. It's true that 0x100 would be 256 but there is no suggestion that it is hexadecimal.

Comment: Have you tried `return val/100.0f;`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I wrong understood.
So the gyroscope data return in int16 x 1000. When I used function:

```
float toFloat(int16_t val) {
    return ((float)val)/1000.0f;
}
```

Now is receiving data good.